# jquery animation loop not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have the following small script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var messages = [
            "Test 0",
            "--- Test 1",
            "------------- Test 2",
            "--------------------------- Test 3"
        ];
        function anim() {
            $('div.news').css({
                right: 0 - $('div.news').width() // reset to off-screen
            });
            $('div.news').animate({ // call animate function on elements with class="scroll"
                right: $(document).width() // animates right value from the original to the documents width (ie if elements right value = the document width, then element is off screen)
            }, 10000); // 10000 is duration in milliseconds (ie 10 seconds)
        }
        for( var msg_loop = 0; msg_loop < messages.length; msg_loop ++ ) {
            $('div.news').text( messages[msg_loop] );
            anim();
        }
    });
</script>
```

using this simple CSS block:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .news {
        border: none;
        position: absolute;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        color: #60FF60;
        right: -900px;
        width: 900px;
    }
</style>
```

and then just a small HTML div below:

```
<div id="newsdiv" class="news">
    Invalid test data
</div>
```

I've tried several iterations of this, and while I can get a single string to work, whenever I use an array as above, it loops the correct number of times but always displays the same text element on each loop.

Further, the css() call above doesn't seem to work, yet if I replace it with a call to animate() using the same right offset (and a 1 millisecond time value), that works.

The goal is just to loop through all the elements of the array, scrolling each in turn.  I'm not sure what I'm not doing correctly.

My browser is Chrome under Windows 7, if that makes a difference.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FQy8P/)

Comment: That loop its cycle almost instantly, what you're seeing is probably the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: Your `anim()` call actually returns almost immediately, so you are running it at high speed in a loop. The actually animation happens asynchronously. You need to add event handlers to the animation to catch it ending.

Comment: Remove the space in `msg_loop ++`.  It should be `msg_loop++`

Comment: @Axel: Whitespace is generally ignored by compilers (including Javascript, C++, C# etc)

Comment: @Axel Nope, like any other unary operator, it's not needed.

Answer (score 2):

As others have commented: your animation is happening asynchronously, while your `for` loop happens all at once. You need to tie them together using the `.animate` callback function. Something like this:

```
function anim(arr, idx) {
    if (idx < arr.length) {
        var txt = arr[idx];
        $('div.news').text(txt).css({
            right: 0 - $('div.news').width()
        });
        $('div.news').animate({
            right: $(document).width()
        }, 10000, function () {
            anim(arr, idx + 1);
        });
    }
}
anim(messages, 0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/ZLHWy/

Comment: Ahhhh, gotcha.  I didn't realize (but should have!) that animate() has internal callbacks.  Thanks!